# Instantiate subclass from superclass

Tags: python

I need to instantiate a subclass from the superclass.

```
class Superclass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        #This should return an instance of subclass1 or subclass2

class Subclass1(Superclass):
    pass
class Subclass2(Superclass):
    pass
```

I want to write:

```
Subclass1.get_instance()
```

and obtain an instance of Subclass1, and same for Subclass2

Comment: If you're okay with accessing this via `Subclass1`, why don't you just do `Subclass1()` and instantiate it the normal way?

Comment: By the same token, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to implement the Singleton pattern?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to make superclass know anything about subclasses

Comment: I do have a reason for wanting to do it but it's a bit complicated, am not trying to implement a singleton.

Comment: @LtWorf: I'd suggest trying to explain it; you may find that someone on SO can provide a better design approach.

Comment: You may want to look into [Creational patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod` :

```
class Superclass(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        #This should return an instance of subclass1 or subclass2
        return cls()

class Subclass1(Superclass):
    pass
class Subclass2(Superclass):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the list of subclasses of a given class you can use the `__subclasses__` method:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Subclass1(MyClass):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Subclass2(MyClass):
...     pass
... 
>>> MyClass.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.Subclass1'>, <class '__main__.Subclass2'>]
```

If you already know the existing subclasses you can simply instantiate them directly:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def getInstance(self):
...             return Subclass1()
... 
>>> class Subclass1(MyClass): pass
... 
>>> MyClass().getInstance()
<__main__.Subclass1 object at 0x1e72d10>
```

Anyway, I *guess* that you are trying to implement the Singleton pattern, in which case I think you should not use a `getInstance` method at all. Just implement it using:

- a module, since modules are singletons
- Reimplementing `__new__` to return the old instance, if an instance already exist
- Using some metaclass

And there are a lot more ways of doing this.

If this is not your aim, then maybe you ought to change design because super-class usually do not have to know about subclasses.

Comment: No singleton, I am trying to avoid reimplementing a static function in the subclasses that would be identical except for the instance used.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this, if you cannot just call `selfclass()` in a classmethod, is to define (or assume) a factory method, and have your superclass method call that factory method on `self`:

```
class Mixinator(object):

      @classmethod # this is not really necessary, but it means you don't need an instance to start with
      def factoryuser(selfclass, *args):
          return selfclass.factory(*args)


      #only define factory if you want Mixinator to be usable on its own
      @classmethod
      def factory(selfclass, *args):
          return selfclass(*args)  # this is a stub.
```

Obviously, child classes should need to have something more involved in their `factory` to make this worthwhile. I'm not sure there's any use-case that can't be solved by replacing `factory` with an appropriate `__new__`, but this is more explicit.